# Como passar o `id` de uma postagem via `post` ultilizando AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Gostaria de execultar um update via `ajax`, mas estou com dificuldade na hora de enviar o `id` da postagem via `post` ou `get` para o formulario externo: `php/editarDespesa.php`. O formulario não esta exibindo os `dados`, porem sem utilizar ajax os dados aparecem no formulario.

Tabela `ec_despesas` têm os seguintes campos:

```
`id, aba, status, nome, categoria, conta, valor, data`
```

---

index.php:

```
<div id="dadosDespesas">
                <?php
                    $despesas = dbRead('despesas', "WHERE aba = 'Despesas'", 'id, nome, categoria, valor, data');

                    if(!$despesas)
                        echo '<h3>Nenhuma Despesa Para Pagar!</h3>';
                    else
                        foreach ($despesas as $visual):
                            $valorNormal = $visual['valor'];
                            $valorDecimal = decimalBr($valorNormal);

                            echo '<li>'
                                    .'<p class="b">'.$visual['nome'].'</p>'
                                    .'<p>'.$visual['categoria'].'</p>'
                                    .'<p>'.$valorDecimal.'</p>'
                                    .'<p>'.$visual['data'].'</p>'
                                .'</li>';

                ?>
                <a class="editarDespesa" href="php/editarDespesas.php?id=<?php echo $visual['id']; ?>">Editar</a>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```

---

controle.js

```
    // ABRE A CAIXA DE FORMULARIO PARA EDITAR
$(".editarDespesa").click(function() {
$("#formularioDespesas[class]") .attr("class","formVisivel");

$.post("php/editarDespesa.php?id=<?php echo $visual['id']; ?>", function(data){
    $("#formularioDespesas").html(data);
});

    return false;
}); });
```

---

editarDespesa.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'database.php';

if( !isset( $_GET['id'] ) || empty($_GET['id']) )
    header('Location: index.php');
else{

    $id   = dbEscape( strip_tags( trim( $_GET['id'] ) ) );
    $post = dbRead( 'despesas', "WHERE id = '{$id}' LIMIT 1");

        $post = $post[0];
} ?>


<div class="titulo">
                    <span>Editar Despesa</span>
                    <a id="fecharFormularioDespesas" class="icon-close"></a>
                </div>
                <div id="conteudo">
                    <form action="" method="post">  
                        <li><p>Descrição</p><input id="nomeDespesas" name="descricao" placeholder="Nome" type="text" value="<?php echo $post['nome']; ?>"></li>
                        <li><p>Valor</p><input id="valorDespesas" name="valor" placeholder="0.00" type="text" value="<?php echo $post['valor']; ?>"></li>
                        <li id="toggle1"><p>pago</p><input id="statusDespesas" type="checkbox" name="status" value="0">
                            <label for="statusDespesas" data-text-true="Sim" data-text-false="Não"><i></i></label>
                        </li>
                        <li><p>Data</p><input id="dataDespesas" name="data" maxlength="10" placeholder="30/12/2014" type="text" value="<?php echo $post['data']; ?>"></li>
                        <li><p>Categoria</p><select id="categoriaDespesas" name="assunto">
                            <option value="<?php echo $post['categoria']; ?>"><?php echo $post['categoria']; ?></option>
                            <option value="Salário">Salário</option>
                            <option value="Investimentos">Investimento</option>
                            <option value="Contas">Conta</option>
                            <option value="Empréstimo">Empréstimo</option>
                            <option value="Serviços prestados">Serviços prestados</option>
                            <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
                        </select></li>
                        <input id="abaDespesas" type="hidden" name="aba" value="Despesas"/>
                        <input id="contaDespesas" type="hidden" name="conta" value="bb"/>
                    </form>

                    <button id="botao_limparDespesas">
                        <span>LIMPAR</span>
                    </button>
                    <button id="butao_alterarDespesas" type="submit">
                        <span>ALTERAR</span>
                    </button>                   
                    <div id="loardDespesas"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Onde está, no HTML, o valor da ID que quer enviar?

Comment: O valor esta sendo pegado do banco de dados que tem uma coluna com o nome "id" e nele esta o valor ex: 33

Comment: Mas quando quer fazer isto `$.post("php/editarDespesa.php?id=<?php echo $visual['id']; ?>"` esse echo o que tem? se o ficheiro js não fôr processado pelo PHP então isso não vai funcionar. Tem de faer echo desse ID para um `data-id` dentro da form. Isto faz-lhe sentido? Então cada form deve ter um ID unico certo?

Comment: o echo contem um numero, esse numero deveria passar para a pagina php/editarDespesa.php, desta forma: "http://localhost/php/editarDespesas.php?id=34" eu só preciso disso, só que utilizando ajax

Comment: Eu percebo, o seu problema é que essa linha de código está num ficheiro `.js` e eu imagino (com bastante certeza) que essa linha está ainda com `?id=<?php echo $visual['id']; ?>` no lado do cliente (quando abre no browser). Então a minha pergunta é cada página deve ter um ID unico certo? ou precisa de IDxs diferentes para o mesmo utilizador/página?

Comment: @DeyvisCharles Dê uma lida no [tour] aceitar uma resposta (e votar quando você tiver esse privilégio) é a melhor forma de agradecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu index.php você dá um `href` à ancora para editar a despesa. Pode usar essa `href` que cria aqui:

```
<a class="editarDespesa" href="php/editarDespesas.php?id=<?php echo $visual['id']; ?>">Editar</a>
```

Ou seja, no seu ficheiro `.js` use assim:

```
$(".editarDespesa").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#formularioDespesas[class]").attr("class", "formVisivel");

    $.post(href , function (data) {
        $("#formularioDespesas").html(data);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sergio você é o cara! muito obrigado mesmo. Você Resolvel meu problema com esse codigo que elaborou. Sinto muito não poder votar na sua resposta, eu preciso ter pelomenos 15 pontos de reputaçaõ, só que sou novo no stackoverflow. Abraços!

Comment: @DeyvisCharles fico contente de ter ajudado. Se quiser pode marcar a resposta como certa/aceite clicando no marcador.

Answer (score 0):

Eu sei que já faz um tempo dessa resposta, mas como algumas pessoas ainda utilizam essa pergunta como base, resolvi dar uma refinada nela seguindo o que @Sergio fez.

```
<a class="editarDespesa" href="#" data-id="<?php echo $visual['id']; ?>">Editar</a>
```

Passar a utilizar o atributo **data** adicionando o valor a ele definindo o **data-id=""**.

E no bloco do javascript inserir assim:

```
$('body').on('click','.editarDespesa',function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).data('id');
var href = 'php/editarDespesas.php?id='+id;
$("#formularioDespesas[class]").attr("class", "formVisivel");

$.post(href , function (data) {
    $("#formularioDespesas").html(data);
});

return false;
});
```

Particularmente prefiro trabalhar dessa forma.